# UITapGestureRecognizer and number of tabs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I add tabgesture to view using

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

how to catch the number of tabs and rest the size of the view after to 2 tabs

best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are setting number of taps required to 1, change the line to...

```
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
```

and it will only fire when there is a double tap.

Comment: yah I got it , how to change the view size

Comment: If its a UIView then set the frame... [view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 200.0)]; for a 100x200 view